# pdo_mysql PHP extension missing in Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: php, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am currently deploying my Laravel application to a kubernetes cluster. I use the same docker image for the actual deployment and a migration job which is deployed via Gitlab using Helm.

The Problem:
Running the migration job failes, because pdo_mysql module is not enabled (missing in php -m)

Things to know:
Running same container with the same command locally `docker run registry.gitlab.com/../master:TAG /bin/sh -c "php artisan:migrate"` - works fine

Application container in the cluster is also working, so pdo_mysql is present.

Scheduler using supervisord to run `php some:command` (which needs pdo_mysql) works too.

.env file is the same for all containers

Deployment file (you can ignore the helm variables)

```
    {{- if .Values.application.migrateCommand -}}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ template "trackableappname" . }}-db-migrate
  labels:
    app: {{ template "appname" . }}
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version| replace "+" "_" }}"
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "0"
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "appname" . }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      imagePullSecrets:
{{ toYaml .Values.image.secrets | indent 10 }}
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "{{ .Values.application.migrateCommand }}"]
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        {{- if .Values.application.secretName }}
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: {{ .Values.application.secretName }}
        {{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

> Update: helm install . --dry-run --debug

```
    ---
# Source: portal/templates/db-migrate-hook.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
    kind: Job
    metadata:
      name: cranky-seahorse-db-migrate
      labels:
        app: cranky-seahorse
        chart: "portal-0.3.0"
        release: cranky-seahorse
        heritage: Tiller
      annotations:
        "helm.sh/hook": pre-upgrade
        "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
        "helm.sh/hook-weight": "0"
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: cranky-seahorse
            release: cranky-seahorse
        spec:
          restartPolicy: Never
          imagePullSecrets:
              - name: gitlab-registry

          containers:
          - name: portal
            image: "gitlab.example.com/group/project:stable"
            command: ["/bin/sh"]
            args: ["-c", "sh migrate.sh"]
            imagePullPolicy: Always
---
```

Comment: Run your helm deployment with `--dry-run --debug` you will see the whole yaml and I guess it would be enough to find a problem.

Comment: @FL3SH the container is created and the script starts to run, so the helm deployment should be fine and wouldn't show any errors?

Comment: Like @FL3SH said, please firstly run deployment with '--dry-run --debug' and check the status.

Comment: I updated my question with the results @abielak

Comment: Please, upvote/accept the answer to let community know about the usefulness, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem can be wrong `php.ini` in `/var/www/html` that was being loaded instead of the right one (`exetension_dir` was being set wrongly) so please check it.

You can run:

```
RUN echo "extension=pdo_mysql" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
 && service apache2 restart
```

This will enable extension code into the `php.ini` and restart apache2 so the new config gets loaded.

What I found also is [github](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/62#issuecomment-467455626) topic about it. You can also try this solution.
I hope it will helps you.